# CRM 2011 how to update a Parent entity field with values from a child/related entity form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dom-events

I am fairly new to CRM and I am using CRM Dynamics 2011. I am trying to read values from an Activity and populate the values into a Lead form when the Activity is saved. The scenario is that , on the Lead form there is a section which holds an Activity, so when I create a new Activity(phone-call,sms,email etc), I want to read the createdon date of that particular activity and set the value to a date field on the parent Lead form. What I have gathered is that I will write a JavaScript function on the Activity , what I am battling to understand is how to write the values of the Activity to the Lead as this function will be OnSave event of an Activity, how do I write those values across to the Parent Lead, Any ideas I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do JavaScript for this.  Create a Workflow against the Activity record (you'll need to be more specific about the type of activity) and create a Workflow like so:-
[image]

You can then set the required field on the parent from the values on the activity.

[image]

You can do it via JavaScript however you shouldn't need to unless you have more complex requirements.

Comment: Hi Campey, This will work fine, the only issue is that when a new activity is created, the process needs to check if the First value is populated(on Lead), then populate the second one when a new activity is created, I find this not possible with a Workflow,unless if I am wrong, so can I get an example/reference of passing data to related entities and so on using JavaScript, unless there is a way I can perform checking within a workflow.

Comment: You can add a condition which would handle this.  In the process you can add a "Check Condition" which allows you to check if a field contains data or is a particular value.  Unless you have a really specific thing to check this should work.  Otherwise look at this post (http://www.avtex.com/blog/2012/01/24/updating-a-child-entity-using-jscript-and-the-rest-endpoint-for-crm-2011).  This is talking about updating a child record however the process is rather similar.  Or there is this one http://mscrmshop.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/how-to-update-parent-record-when-child.html